# How can I submit form fields from iOS to a UIWebView using Xamarin?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I currently have a simple website with a password login form:

```
<input type="text" id="passwd" name="passwd" />
```

I want to be able to type in a pin number in my iOS app and have it submit the password form inside of my web view.

I'm currently loading my view using this:

```
myWebView.LoadRequest (new NSUrlRequest (new NSUrl("mysite.com")));
```

I found where someone can do this using obj-c, but I'm not sure how to implement this using C# and Xamarin. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: is your html form using GET or POST ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do the trick :

```
string password = "1234";
var req = new NSMutableUrlRequest (new NSUrl ("http://example.com"));
req.HttpMethod = "POST";
req.Body = NSData.FromString(String.Format("passwd={0}", password));
//req["Content-Length"] = req.Body.Length.ToString();
//req["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8";
myWebView.LoadRequest (req);
```

Comment: sorry should have used NSMutableRequest to be able to set the method. I have updated the answer.

Comment: maybe your site has an issue, cause I've tested with "http://www.hashemian.com/tools/form-post-tester.php/test123" as the url, and it's printing my post in the webview

Comment: It looks like it was posting, but did not load the page or something. I removed the Content-Type and Content-Length and it worked fine.

Comment: This helped me, thanks. It worked fine without "Content-Length" header and with "charset=utf-8" removed from the end of "Content-Type" header. I have used WKWebView to send Post request like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is for `UIWebview` (Deprecated from April 2020

```
var request = new NSMutableUrlRequest(new NSUrl(new 
    NSString("Url - here")));
    request.Body = "Data for Post";
    request.HttpMethod = "POST";
    LoadRequest(request);
```

This is for `WkWebview`

```
    var request = new NSMutableUrlRequest(new NSUrl(new 
    NSString("Url - here")));
    request.Body = "Data for Post";
    request.HttpMethod = "POST";
    request["Content-Length"] = request.Body.Length.ToString();
    request["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
    charset=utf-8";
```

LoadRequest(request);